# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток) Обьясните как исправить ошибку)

```
 private double E;

double Efficiency() {

    double[] firstEtalon = firstEtalon();
    double [] secondEtalon  = secondEtalon();
    int n1 = 0,n2 = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < r1; i++ ) {
        for (int j = 0; j < r2; j++ ) {

            if ((firstEtalon[i] < r1 ) && (secondEtalon[j] > r2)){
                n1++;
            } else if ((secondEtalon[j] < r2 )&& (firstEtalon[i] >r1)){
                n2++;
            }
        }
        E = ((n1+n2)/160);
        System.out.println(E);
    }
    return E;
```

Вот:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 80
at Laba.Distance.Efficiency(Distance.java:77)
at Laba.Test.main(Test.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Большое спасибо)

Comment: Чему равны `r1` и `r2`?

Comment: @post_zeew Вам числа или то как я их вызываю?)

Comment: Смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 2):

В выражении `firstEtalon[i]` или `secondEtalon[j]` Вы Выходите за пределы массива.

Значение `r1` должно быть не более `firstEtalon.length`, а значение `r2` – не более `secondEtalon.length`.

Как исправить – зависит от того, что Вы в Вашей программе делаете и что хотите получить.

Можно заменить `r1` на `firstEtalon.length` и `r2` на `firstEtasecondEtalonlon.length`, например (это исправит ошибку, но может сломать логику).

Comment: Я же только сравниваю число в ячейке массива с нужным числом(r). Какие тут могут быть приделы массива?

Comment: @ДашаНовикова, Допустим у Вас есть массив `array` на десять элементов, при обращении, например, `array[15]` Вы выйдете за пр**Е**делы массива и получите `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.